# Understand Observable.fromArray in RxJava

Tags: observable, rx-java

I am trying to learn different operators of RxJava. I was a little confused between Observable.just and Observable.fromArray() and how they emit Observables.

Individual integers works fine, but to understand the difference better, I am trying to use arrays. I have below code which works fine for individual integers , but when I pass array, it says some compilation error and I cannot understand how to resolve.

**Code for Individual Integers**

```
Observable.fromArray(10,20,30).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Util.d("Emit Integers : "+ it)
            })
```

The Output is :

```
Emit Integers : 10
Emit Integers : 20
Emit Integers : 30
```

Now to emit integers from some list I try below code:

```
var numbers = arrayOf<Int>(1, 2, 3)
Observable.fromArray(numbers).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            Util.d("Emit Integers: "+ it)
         })
```

The Output I get is

```
Emit Integers: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@8a69c02
```

What I expect is to return each item of array as Observable. Is it not possible with fromArray() ? If not, What is the use of Observable.fromArray()

Answer (score 7):

According to their [doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#from) `fromArray()` only supports **reference arrays**. But in kotlin `arrayOf<Int>()` returns `Array` object. If we put a kotlin `Array` object in `fromArray()` method, it creates array of `Array` object (in java, it will be `Array[]`). So after subscription `Observable` returns that object of `Array`. 
But if we put items in `fromArray()` method, it will create array of `Int`. So after subscription it returns `Int`.
If you want to iterate over any **mutable iterable**, then you can try `Observable.fromIterable()`.

Comment: makes sense now. that is what was strange that it works in java but not in kotlin. You explained very well.

Comment: Although this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#fromarray it says `RxJava does not support primitive arrays, only (generic) reference arrays.`

Comment: Sorry,  I interchange supported types mistakenly. But idea is close to this. I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
        val arr = arrayOf("111", "222")

        Observable.fromArray(*arr)
            .subscribe {
                Log.d("test", "$it")
            }

        Observable.fromIterable(arr.asIterable())
            .subscribe {
                Log.d("test", "$it")
            }
```

Comment: Please try to add some explanation.

Comment: We use  the spread operator  ( * ) to pass an array's elements as the arguments

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using fromIterable operator

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf(1,2,3))
                .subscribe({
                    Util.d("Emit Integers from list: "+ it)
                })
```

And summarized it in the post here : http://kukroid.com/2019/12/28/difference-between-observable-just-and-observable-fromarray/

Answer (score 1):

In short, `arrayOf(10, 20, 30)` creates an `int[]` which is not compatible with `Object[]` the `fromArray` requires, hence it emits the entire `int[]` array as a single item. RxJava doesn't support primitive array sources. If you can't transform the `int[]` array into an `Integer[]` array, you can do an indexed-for equivalent:

```
 var a = arrayOf(10, 20, 30)

 Observable.range(0, a.size)
           .map { index -> a[index] }
           .subscribe { println(it) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Converts an Array into an ObservableSource that emits the items in the Array.
 * <p>
 * <img width="640" height="315" src="https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/from.png" alt="">
 * <dl>
 *  <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 *  <dd>{@code fromArray} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param items
 *            the array of elements
 * @param <T>
 *            the type of items in the Array and the type of items to be emitted by the resulting ObservableSource
 * @return an Observable that emits each item in the source Array
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: From</a>
 */

@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
@NonNull
public static <T> Observable<T> fromArray(T... items) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(items, "items is null");
    if (items.length == 0) {
        return empty();
    }
    if (items.length == 1) {
        return just(items[0]);
    }
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableFromArray<T>(items));
}
```

`fromArray` accept items. here `(10, 20, 30) != arrayOf<Int>(1, 2, 3)` two different things. 10, 20 ,30 its self as a item while  `numbers` array its self a item. I hope you can understand what I am try to explain.